# Why does the choice of origin affect the wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, coordinate-systems

Consider a particle in a 1D-Box.

The box ranges from x=0 to x=l in the first case, and from x=-l/2 to x=l/2 in the second case.

The only difference I see is that the origin is shifted.

On solving the Time Independent Schroedinger's Equation, we get different wave functions in both the cases.

Why is it that the choice of origin affects the wave function?

Do observables too depend on the choice of origin? As surely the particle "knows" that it has a region of L length to move about.

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same? In all aspects of physics different boundary conditions for differential equations will lead to different solutions to the differential equations. Why would this be any different?

Comment: Please note that it is not $\psi$ but $|\psi|^2$ that has a physical interpretation!!

Comment: Do you realize that sines and cosines are just shifted versions of each other?

Comment: @G.Smith Are they? on solving them I got different quantisation condtitions and not just simply shifted wave functions.

Comment: @AmeyJoshi True, but isn't the "state" of the particle completely specified by the wave function, therefore, different wavefunctions imply different state?

Comment: @AaronStevens I know that mathematically it must be different. But will this also change the physically observable quantities?

Comment: @Hrsht you are absolutely correct. Both wavefunctions completely specify the system. Although they differ, their physical content is identical.

Comment: @Hrsht The eigenvalues for your observables were different from the moment you set the boundary conditions. In the case for the wave function when the box ranges from 0 to L, it’s impossible for you to get an eigenvalue of -L/2 for example. Now it’s essentially describing the same physical problem but because you’re describing the box in translated coordinate systems you’ll naturally end up with different mathematical representations.

Comment: @AmeyJoshi Your comment suggests that only $\psi^2 $ is physically relevant but that is only the charge density. $\psi$ contains more information such as energy, momentum, angular momentum.

Comment: @my2cts Charge density? Do you mean probability density?

Comment: @Thatpotatoisaspy Your first comment doesn't make any sense. What do you mean an Eigenvalue of $-L/2$?  Three quantization the OP talks about is energy, not position.

Comment: @Hrsht If you're getting different energy eigenvalues then you made an error somewhere.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens I saw them just mention “observables” in general in their post and their comments here, and since like you said, if OP is getting different Energy eigenvalues then they must have made an error somewhere, so i assumed they were talking about position.

Comment: *I got different quantisation condtitions and not just simply shifted wave functions.* If you don’t show any of your work, we can’t tell you what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When plotted both cases are indistinguishable. The plots only differ by what you specify on the x-axis.

Physics is invariant under space and time translation. This property is closely related to energy and momentum conservation via Noether's theorem.

Comment: *Physics is invariant under space and time translation.* I would consider qualifying this statement. You make it sound like momentum is conserved in every system.

Comment: @AaronStevens In every isolated system momentum is conserved. Perhaps not in general relativity if you'd like to comment on that. I consider it off topic here.

Comment: I didn't say anything about GR, and your answer doesn't say anything about isolated systems, which is a kind of qualifier I was mentioning in my first comment.

Comment: @AaronStevens The statement "Physics is invariant under space and time translation." is self contained. Hence I had to guess after the direction of your thinking.